# Python pandas dataframe slicing, with if condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame object, with multiple columns: `business_id`, `categories`, `type_of_business`...

I have managed to create a smaller DataFrame with only `business_id` and `categories` by column indexing on the original DataFrame object.

`categories` is a list of certain strings.Example: `['Restaurant, 'food', 'bakery']` - for each `business_id`.

One of the categories is `Restaurants`. How would I retrieve only those business ids where the word `Restaurants` is in the categories list.

Pseudocode:

```
for row in smaller_DataFrame:
    if 'Restaurants' in row['categories']:
        add this business_id to some dictionary.
```

I am interested in how I would incorporate the `if` condition in a DataFrame object.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with map:

```
df[df.categories.map(lambda cats: 'Restaurants' in cats)]
```

Comment: I had used this lambda expression form before but it completely slipped my mind. Thanks for your help Viktor.

Answer (score 4):

Selecting rows according to a boolean condition is called *masking* in the documentation.

```
df[df['categories'].isin(['Restaurant', 'food', 'bakery'])]
```

As an aside, I see you've been downvoted. It's better if you include a few sample rows of your DataFrame and an example of your desired result.

To make it case insensitive, stick `.str.lowercase()` before `.isin`, and make the list of categories all lowercase.

Comment: I think that his `categories` column contain lists, not single values.

Comment: Yup, whatever it is he will have an answer :)

Comment: no the categories is a list of string as in each row contains a list of string categories. I think @DanAllan misunderstood me? Sorry for the confusion. I will be more descriptive in the future.