# python dataframe lowercase slicing

Tags: python, dataframe, slice

I have a dataframe. I want to slice it by checking if the value contains a string. For example, this code works:

```
data_df[data_df['column1'].str.contains('test')]
```

But I first want to set my column1 to be all lowercase first. So being the n00b that I am, I tried:

```
data_df[data_df['column1'].lower().str.contains('test')]
```

Of course the Python gods gave me no mercy and gave me an AttributeError. Any tips on how I can slice a dataframe based on a substring but first make everything into lowercase first?

I feel like the following post is very close to my answer but I can't get it to work exactly how I described up there:
[Python pandas dataframe slicing, with if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790233/python-pandas-dataframe-slicing-with-if-condition)

Thanks Python pros!!!

Comment: You need str accessor before `lower()` as well: `data_df[data_df['column1'].str.lower().str.contains('test')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using apply()

```
data_df[data_df['column1'].apply(str.lower).str.contains('test')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the apply:

```
data_df[data_df['column1'].str.lower().str.contains('test')]
```